# Export georeferenced .tif in ArcGIS Pro with a transparent background

Tags: arcgis-pro, geotiff-tiff, export

I am a graduate student relatively new to using ArcGIS. I have georeferenced a bunch of historical images and I want to export them as .tif files with the georeferencing information included. When I export them, they come out with a large black background surrounding the image. I know I can get rid of this background by setting a NoData value of 0, but these are scanned photographs and some areas in the image itself also have a value of 0, so this also results in holes in the image. Does anyone have some good suggestions to get around this problem? I am running ArcGIS Pro 3.1 for desktop.

Comment: are you doing any pre-processing of the scanned image? in the past had to use photoshop to clean up rgb values to avoid the holes when exporting.

Comment: I am not doing any pre-processing. I thought about editing the image to remove 0 values, but I am not sure how to do that... I will look further into it.

Comment: GNU Image Manipulation Program (GIMP). Is a good alternative to Photoshop if have no budget. https://www.gimp.org/

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/image-analyst/h-changing-nodata-cells-to-a-value.htm

Comment: How I do it, requires spatial analyst, set the band NoData values, for each band create an IsNull raster, with Cell Statistics sum all the IsNull rasters, create a conditional raster where (CellStat == 3,1,3), convert the binary raster to polygon (no_simplify) which will give you a polygon of where NoData exists, you can now edit the polygon to remove small islands of NoData (select the outside, switch selection and then dissolve), delete the ephemera to get a polygon of the valid area. Using clip mangement extract the valid area. I know it's a lot of steps but the first part can be scripted.

Comment: Lemme ask a basic question: Why do you want to get rid of the NoData (ie black background) perimeter values?  It is a pretty standard way of receiving off-axis photogrammetry, so why are you looking to strip these out?  Also, would a pure white background be any better for you?